# How to make a dropdown menu on hover desktop and slidedown in mobile but on click?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

*Can somebody help me?*

I have already **tried** in some ways but still i couldn't get that what i **want**.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="li-first">Tab 1
    <ul class="nav-2">
      <li>Element 1 Tab 1</li>
      <li>Element 2 Tab 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li-first">Tab 2
    <ul class="nav-2">
      <li>Element 1 Tab 2</li>
      <li>Element 2 Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-2{
     display:none;
     list-style:none;
}

li{
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.li-first{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.li-first ul{
    padding:0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .li-first:hover .nav-2{
        display:block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){

    .li-first{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropactiv .nav-2{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".li-first").click(function(){

            if (!$(this).hasClass("dropactiv")){
                $(".li-first").removeClass("dropactiv");
                $(this).addClass("dropactiv");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $(".li-first").removeClass("dropactiv");
            }
    });
```

Comment: _Thanks!_  but i want on media screen **768px** to be on **click** with slide down effect and to remove hover effect

Comment: Your mobile phone will handle it right and will dropdown when you click on it.

Comment: You still want no dropdown on hover >768px? then i will update the code, but that's how it's normally used on websites

Comment: Yea ! I know what you mean You are **saying** it right but i want like this . and i want to say to you , **really really thanks :D **

Comment: Can i make this with slideDown jQuery only for mobile ?

Comment: sure. and what should happen, when a desktop with <768px visits the site? then hover?

Comment: Everything its working find just like you did but when im trying to slide effect first time its working, but on desktop second time on click its working   how can i restore to default on resize

Comment: right now it doesn't work on desktop for <768px. what should it do there? hover or with click? (so mobile is click always and what should happen on desktop for very small screens?)

Comment: i maked dropdown with tranform translate larger than 768px , now lower than 768px i want this to be on click with slidetoggle how can do this , i have removed hover effect on mobile i have maked click function but without effect i want with effect. im sorry im not good in english hopes you get the question now thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, now how to animate on mobile, on mobile nav its display : block

Comment: sorry what's wrong on mobile? On what resolution? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Am I right? What you want: 
Desktop:
- screen <768px slidetoggle on click
- screen >768px hover with the css solution

Mobil:
- slidetoggle on click for all screen resolutions